# Apache Storm application fails at run

Tags: java, maven, classpath

I am encountering a problem at runtime, when my application can't find classes listed in maven as dependencies at compile. The application compiles without issue.

The application is as follows

```
package com.ender.storm;

import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;

public class HelloStorm {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Config config = new Config();
        config.put("inputFile", args[0]);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
        config.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_DEBUG, false);
        config.setDebug(false);

        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout("line-reader-spout", new LineReaderSpout());
        builder.setBolt("word-spitter", new WordSpitterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("line-reader-spout");
        builder.setBolt("word-counter", new WordCounterBolt()).shuffleGrouping("word-spitter");

        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology("HelloStorm", config, builder.createTopology());
        Thread.sleep(10000);

        cluster.shutdown();
    }

}
```

The LineReaderSpout looks as follows

package com.ender.storm;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map;

import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LineReaderSpout implements IRichSpout {
    private SpoutOutputCollector collector;
    private FileReader fileReader;
    private boolean completed = false;
    private TopologyContext context;
    @Override
    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context,
            SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        try {
            this.context = context;
            this.fileReader = new FileReader(conf.get("inputFile").toString());
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading file "
                    + conf.get("inputFile"));
        }
        this.collector = collector;
    }

    @Override
    public void nextTuple() {
        if (completed) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            }
        }
        String str;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        try {
            while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                this.collector.emit(new Values(str), str);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error reading typle", e);
        } finally {
            completed = true;
        }

    }
    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("line"));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        try {
            fileReader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public boolean isDistributed() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public void activate() {
    }
    @Override
    public void deactivate() {
    }
    @Override
    public void ack(Object msgId) {
    }
    @Override
    public void fail(Object msgId) {
    }
    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

error shows

```
jender:Storm$ java -cp target/Storm-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.ender.storm.HelloStorm test.txt 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichSpout
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2615)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:2856)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1668)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.getMainMethod(LauncherHelper.java:494)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:486)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 6 more
```

**Maven version:**

```
Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_75, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-i386/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.13.0-44-generic", arch: "i386", family: "unix"
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.ender.storm</groupId>
  <artifactId>Storm</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Storm</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
         <plugins>
             <plugin>
                 <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                 <version>3.1</version>
                 <configuration>
                     <source>1.7</source>
                     <target>1.7</target>
                     <compilerArgument></compilerArgument>
                 </configuration>
             </plugin>
         </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.storm</groupId>
      <artifactId>storm-core</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1-incubating</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>redis.clients</groupId>
      <artifactId>jedis</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The jar file created by 'mvn package' contains:

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
com/
com/ender/
com/ender/storm/
com/ender/storm/App.class
com/ender/storm/HelloStorm.class
com/ender/storm/RedisPubSubSpout$ListenerThread$1.class
com/ender/storm/RedisPubSubSpout$ListenerThread.class
com/ender/storm/LineReaderSpout.class
com/ender/storm/WordSpitterBolt.class
com/ender/storm/RedisPubSubSpout.class
com/ender/storm/WordCounterBolt.class
META-INF/maven/
META-INF/maven/com.ender.storm/
META-INF/maven/com.ender.storm/Storm/
META-INF/maven/com.ender.storm/Storm/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/com.ender.storm/Storm/pom.properties
```

It compiles fine under Ubuntu 14.04, which makes me think that the required dependencies are found, but the apache-storm jars aren't included in the jar created by maven. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your jar didn't contains any dependencies, usually jar contains only classes of a project, not a dependencies.

So you need to add them to classpath, or to create big jar with all dependencies.

For creating big jar take a look at [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/descriptor-refs.html#jar-with-dependencies) (goal - jar with dependencies)

> Use jar-with-dependencies as the descriptorRef of your assembly-plugin
>   configuration in order to create a JAR which contains the binary
>   output of your project, along its the unpacked dependencies. This
>   built-in descriptor produces an assembly with the classifier
>   jar-with-dependencies using the JAR archive format.

or at [Maven Shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) for this you need to add to pom.xml something like this: (but please read manual for shade plugin first)

```
<build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <artifactSet>
                <excludes>
                  <exclude>junit:junit</exclude>
                </excludes>
              </artifactSet>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```